# Makefile C verification

Tags: c, makefile

I am new to C and I'd like you guys to check my makefile - I have no idea if it's correct.

Visual Studio command prompt result:

D:\Programy\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>nmake -f C:\Users\MStranko\Desktop\P
ORR\Makefile

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

This left no output in same directory as files, so leaves me wondering what have I done wrong.

Here's my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-O3 -fopenmp
LDLIBS=-lm

all: main
main: main.o metodaJacobiego.o metodaJacobiegoR.o metodaGaussaJordana.o metodaGaussaJordanaR.o metodaAsynchroniczna.o metodaAsynchronicznaR.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o main main.o metodaJacobiego.o metodaJacobiegoR.o metodaGaussaJordana.o metodaGaussaJordanaR.o metodaAsynchroniczna.o metodaAsynchronicznaR.o $(LDLIBS)
main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)　-c main.c
metodaJacobiego.o: metodaJacobiego.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)　-c metodaJacobiego.c
metodaJacobiegoR.o: metodaJacobiegoR.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)　-c metodaJacobiegoR.c
metodaGaussaJordana.o: metodaGaussaJordana.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)　-c metodaGaussaJordana.c
metodaGaussaJordanaR.o: metodaGaussaJordanaR.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)　-c metodaGaussaJordanaR.c
metodaAsynchroniczna.o: metodaAsynchroniczna.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)　-c metodaAsynchroniczna.c
metodaAsynchronicznaR.o: metodaAsynchronicznaR.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)　-c metodaAsynchronicznaR.c
```

Comment: Your basic problem is that you're trying to use examples from GNU/Linux and other UNIX systems, but you're running on Windows.  The above makefile is running GCC, which is the GNU compiler, not Microsoft Visual C/C++.  It's also likely that most of the makefiles you find will be written for GNU make, while you're running Microsoft nmake which is not the same thing.  You need to either switch to GNU/Linux as an operating system, or search out examples specifically for Windows platforms.

Comment: Or, of course, install Cygwin or MinGW which try to provide, more or less, a GNU toolchain on your Windows system, and not use Visual Studio.

Comment: would this makefile work on linux then? I do have cygwin, need to download makefile and gcc then.

Comment: ...or download GNU Make for Windows.  You don't need to download some big package to use Make; I maintain a minor fork of it here: https://github.com/pololu/make/downloads

Comment: GNU make for Windows won't help if the first line of your makefile is `CC = gcc` :-)

Comment: Ah yes, so he should also install MinGW.  But does that come with make?

Comment: That makefile will work on GNU/Linux, yes, _assuming_ that each of the recipe lines (`$(CC) ...`) has an actual TAB character as the first character on those lines.  It can't be spaces.

Comment: Well, it's kinda tough to do on windows, I tried saving it in .rtf and deleting the .rtf from name. No idea how to do it better.

Comment: I would definitely _not_ stick with Visual Studio if you want to learn C.  Microsoft has no interest in C and they do not support it, basically.  Their C++ compiler is quite good, but C... not.

Comment: You need to get a better editor, that's all.  You need to find a text editor or programmer's editor.  You should never try to write code with a word processor like Word, or even something like Notepad.  There are plenty of free text editors out there; downloading one is your very first task.

Comment: Hmm, I kinda forgot about my notepad++. All this C stuff threw me off my pace, I'm way more used to java :D